# How can I include macros / other templates with a FunctionLoader in Jinja2?

Tags: jinja2

I'm trying to use a sandboxed Jinja2 environment to handle template customizations.

I've tried using both a DictLoader and FunctionLoader, but keep running into similar issues...  I'm mostly concerned with FunctionLoader now.

I can't manage to `include` or `import` another template (which contains macros).  The FuctionLoader's specified "load" function is never called for the referenced templates.

I've tried with no luck:

- just expecting an import would hit the loader using basic 'import' and 'include' syntax
- passing the loader into the context , seeing if it might pull in that way
- passing a dict of templates into the context, also hoping it might pull in
- a few more things , all of which I forgot

I'm sure there's got to be a way to support this - can someone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The import syntax must use quoted strings.

Bad:

```
{% import utils %}
{% import utils.macros as macros %}
{% from utils.macros import macro_1 , macro_2 %}
```

Good:

```
{% import "utils" as utils %}
{% import "utils.macros" as macros %}
{% from "utils.macros" import macro_1 , macro_2 %}
```

The quoted string is passed into the `FunctionLoader` or used as the key with the `DictLoader`

Comment: as a side note: this behavior is not mentioned in the official docs at all.